# How to build fault-tolerant aggregations in Esper CEP

Tags: real-time, distributed-computing, esper, complex-event-processing

As per Esper (CEP) docs it is standalone which doesn't connect to any DB or external systems and does all aggregations by keeping minimal past data in memory.

So if I am having an aggregate for last 1 hour window and if the Esper container node dies in between, wouldn't we lose the aggregation data permanently?

How to handle such scenarios with Esper?

Thanks,
Harish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its handled by EsperHA but that is not open source.